# Sometimes different representation of bootstrap glyphicons

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I coded a mobile website and uses glyphicons. In my responsive design (you can see below) I have sometimes inexplicable different representations of the glyphicons. Correct representation should be the little black arrow and the icon of a cam, but sometimes I get something else, e.g. a piece of cake (yeah I like cake ;) ) or a magnifier.

[image]

[image]

Code of the glyphicons:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

This code above uses the following CSS Class of Bootstrap:

```
font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
```

The representation is sometimes correct and sometimes false (have a look at the time on my screenshots).
Did you ever seen something like this?

It happend very seldom. I saw it only on my iPhone 5 with the current Version of iOS (9.3.1). I can't reproduce it.

Comment: _First you need a charger and sleep._ and second this will get limited audience as not much people having iphone and some won't get the issue.

Comment: please check this  [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13488) and try to remove woff2 font file from @front-face.